# Android: Top to bottom Animation and ProgressBar iocn on top of the view gesture on RecyclerView(or other approch)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, view, android-animation

In the app, if the user swap the finger from top to bottom then the existing row will drag from top to bottom with some extent and the progress bar icon will show on the top of the screen.
Here I need to do some API calls or fetch data from the database. Then add some rows on the top of the RecyclerView.

I found the same type of animation on one of the iOS app, screenshot is attached.

Is there any way to achieve the same or any android library by which I can achieve this?

I tried `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()` but didn't get any leads.

[image]

Comment: Do you want animation like that or Pull to refresh only?

Comment: Yes, both the pull to refresh animation like the above animation and API call on the pull to refresh.

Comment: Libraries are outdated...  I think you need to migrate... check here https://android-arsenal.com/tag/78?category=1

Comment: This repo looks similar to that...... https://github.com/android-cjj/Android-MaterialRefreshLayout?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2492.

Answer (score 0):

Put your recyclerview inside a SwipeRefreshLayout, it will give you this functionality out of the box.
Then you can easily call your api for refreshing data like this,

```
 swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
        //your api call here
 }
```